# Добавить круглый фон к иконке и выровнять её относительно границы фона

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve">
    <path style="fill:#FBBB00;" d="M113.47,309.408L95.648,375.94l-65.139,1.378C11.042,341.211,0,299.9,0,256
        c0-42.451,10.324-82.483,28.624-117.732h0.014l57.992,10.632l25.404,57.644c-5.317,15.501-8.215,32.141-8.215,49.456
        C103.821,274.792,107.225,292.797,113.47,309.408z"/>
    <path style="fill:#518EF8;" d="M507.527,208.176C510.467,223.662,512,239.655,512,256c0,18.328-1.927,36.206-5.598,53.451
        c-12.462,58.683-45.025,109.925-90.134,146.187l-0.014-0.014l-73.044-3.727l-10.338-64.535
        c29.932-17.554,53.324-45.025,65.646-77.911h-136.89V208.176h138.887L507.527,208.176L507.527,208.176z"/>
    <path style="fill:#28B446;" d="M416.253,455.624l0.014,0.014C372.396,490.901,316.666,512,256,512
        c-97.491,0-182.252-54.491-225.491-134.681l82.961-67.91c21.619,57.698,77.278,98.771,142.53,98.771
        c28.047,0,54.323-7.582,76.87-20.818L416.253,455.624z"/>
    <path style="fill:#F14336;" d="M419.404,58.936l-82.933,67.896c-23.335-14.586-50.919-23.012-80.471-23.012
        c-66.729,0-123.429,42.957-143.965,102.724l-83.397-68.276h-0.014C71.23,56.123,157.06,0,256,0
        C318.115,0,375.068,22.126,419.404,58.936z"/>
    </svg>
```

Изначально не было фона "серый круг" Попытался добавить, но выровнять не удается. Возможно поравить то так, чтобы значок гугла бул в той же пропорции к фону?

Answer (score 1):

```html
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-180 -180 870 870" xml:space="preserve">
            <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="50%" fill="#adadad2b"></circle>
    <path style="fill:#FBBB00;" d="M113.47,309.408L95.648,375.94l-65.139,1.378C11.042,341.211,0,299.9,0,256
        c0-42.451,10.324-82.483,28.624-117.732h0.014l57.992,10.632l25.404,57.644c-5.317,15.501-8.215,32.141-8.215,49.456
        C103.821,274.792,107.225,292.797,113.47,309.408z"></path>
    <path style="fill:#518EF8;" d="M507.527,208.176C510.467,223.662,512,239.655,512,256c0,18.328-1.927,36.206-5.598,53.451
        c-12.462,58.683-45.025,109.925-90.134,146.187l-0.014-0.014l-73.044-3.727l-10.338-64.535
        c29.932-17.554,53.324-45.025,65.646-77.911h-136.89V208.176h138.887L507.527,208.176L507.527,208.176z"></path>
    <path style="fill:#28B446;" d="M416.253,455.624l0.014,0.014C372.396,490.901,316.666,512,256,512
        c-97.491,0-182.252-54.491-225.491-134.681l82.961-67.91c21.619,57.698,77.278,98.771,142.53,98.771
        c28.047,0,54.323-7.582,76.87-20.818L416.253,455.624z"></path>
    <path style="fill:#F14336;" d="M419.404,58.936l-82.933,67.896c-23.335-14.586-50.919-23.012-80.471-23.012
        c-66.729,0-123.429,42.957-143.965,102.724l-83.397-68.276h-0.014C71.23,56.123,157.06,0,256,0
        C318.115,0,375.068,22.126,419.404,58.936z"></path>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо, добавить поясняющий текст, как вы решили свою проблему